# Docker Exec -> dotnet: not found

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-desktop

I have created a very simple .NET Core 8 command line application with Docker support (using Visual Studio 2022).

I can run this program named [core-6-api-console-client](https://github.com/hemantshelar/core-6-api-console-client) inside a Docker container using Visual Studio:

[image]

Inside the Docker desktop, I can see one image has been created `core6apiconsoleclient` and running a container named `core-6-api-console-client`.

Through the Docker desktop, I `Exec` into container `core-6-api-console-client` and typed the command shown below:

[image]

```
$ dotnet --version
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '--version' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

I am under the impression that the Docker image `core6apiconsoleclient:dev` should have `dotnet` included within it.

Here is the snap of layer details of the image:

[image]

Any idea, why I am getting the `The command could not be loaded` error?

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has dotnet but not dotnet sdks

It has dotnet runtime

just use `dotnet --list-runtimes`